# Finding $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ if the matrix $A$ is given

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

We have a matrix of the linear representation $f:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^2$ in the standard basis by $f(x) = A^{T}x$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&5\\4&7\\10&31\\21&3\end{pmatrix}$

Find the $\operatorname{rank}$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f)$

So, the $\operatorname{rank}=2$, it was explained to me that the $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ should be the linearly independent vectors. Would it, in this case, be $(-1,5)^T$ or $(-1,5)^T,(4,7)^T$?

Comment: $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ not vice versa

Comment: This is how the task is written

Comment: Sorry, I see, linear operator is $A^T$ not $A$ itself. Here the main idea to understand is that columns of matrix are images of the corresponding basis vectors. Rank is the maximum size of linear independent subsystem. Here rank can be greater than 2 due to image space dimension. You found 2 linear independent vectors: $\textbf{v}_1 = (-1, 5)^T$ and $\textbf{v}_2 = (4, 7)^T$, so they are image basis and Im$ f = \{\alpha_1\textbf{v}_1 + \alpha_2\textbf{v}_2: \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb R\}=\mathbb R^2$

Comment: The image is the *span* of the columns of $A^\intercal$ (or the rows of $A$). A maximal linearly independent subset of the columns of $A^\intercal$ will then be a basis of the image. In the case of the matrix $A$ you are asked about, any two columns of $A^\intercal$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$, the image of $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now $Im(f) = \{f(x) : x \in \mathbb{R}^{4}\} = 
\{a \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix} + c \begin{pmatrix}10 \\ 31 \end{pmatrix} + d \begin{pmatrix}21 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Now let $ e_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}, e_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}$ are basis of $Im(f)$ as $\begin{pmatrix}10 \\ 31 \end{pmatrix} = 2\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} + 3\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}21 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = -5\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} + 4\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}$. It is also very clear to see that $e_{1},e_{2}$ is also linear independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.